# Can you make a class enumerable via extension methods? In particular, System.Range

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

I'm using the latest C# 8 right now, I was toying around with the new System.Range, and wanted to see if something like

```
foreach (int i in 5..8)
{ 
}
```

was possible, but at the time of writing this (using the absolute cutting edge preview) is giving me an error.

I then wondered if I could make it enumerable by doing something like the following in a static class, since maybe the `foreach` loop doesn't actually care and just wants the existence of some method to be available, so I tried:

```
public static IEnumerator GetEnumerator(this Range range) 
{
    // ...
}
```

however the compiler was not happy with this.

Is this possible? Or am I just implementing enumerable wrong? The error message in the IDE was telling me that `GetEnumerator()` needs to be available for `foreach` to run, however since I don't have access to the class and can't simply do `: IEnumerable<int>` and then generate the methods from it and do what is needed, I don't know if this means I'm stuck or whether I'm coding this incorrectly.

My error:

```
    foreach (int i in 1..5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
```

> [CS1579] foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Range' because 'Range' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'

and

> $ dotnet --version
>
> 3.0.100-preview8-013656

with a project targeting `netcoreapp3.0` and the C# language level is `preview`

Comment: But this `foreach (int i in 5..8)` should just work out of the box without doing anything.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I posted both the exact compiler error, my C#/.NET info, and project parameters as further evidence of either it not working, or me somehow messing up.

Comment: Can you try with regular .NET and not core and see if it works then?

Comment: @CodingYoshi Trying regular .NET now tells me `System.Range is not defined`. Also before I changed to regular .NET, I can use ranges fine (like `arr[1..4]`) but not in a foreach loop.

Comment: Ranges aren't *naturally* enumerable, because they need context. For example, what would you expect `foreach(int i in 1..^10)` to do? Better for it to just not work at all than fail at execution time, IMO.

Comment: It's probably better to stick with [Enumerable.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netframework-4.8) which is designed explicitly for this use case than to try and shoehorn `System.Range`, though I sympathize with the desire to use the range syntax.

Comment: But still, `foreach(int index in 0..20)` just looks better then `foreach(int index in Enumerable.Range(0, 20)` ;)

Comment: BTW It is possible to use this syntax, but only in Framework projects. Because .net Framework doesn't have Index and Range you have to define those structs yourself, if you want to use them. Then you can just define `GetEnumerator()` as well. - But of course this is just a hack and of course in no way recomended in real applications!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the `foreach` loop doesn't work with extension methods, unlike (say) `await`. It *is* pattern-based in that it doesn't require implementing `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerable` - if you have an appropriate `GetEnumerator()` **instance** method returning an appropriate type (with `MoveNext()` and `Current` members), that's fine. But the compiler doesn't look for a `GetEnumerator()` extension method like you've got. It has been [proposed](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/600), but I don't know of any plan to do this, and I'd be very surprised if it were in C# 8 (given the [list of features](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/Language%20Feature%20Status.md)).

You'd need to write an extension method like this:

```
 public static IEnumerable<int> AsEnumerable(this Range range)
 {
     ...
 }
```

and then you could use

```
 foreach (int x in (1..5).AsEnumerable())
```

... but you'd still need to work out what to do if either index is "from the end" instead of "from the start", and I'm not sure it's terribly useful to have that as an execution-time-only check, really.

Basically, ranges are designed mostly for slicing *within another context* rather than being standalone.